# C# , How can i build a DateTime object from a datetime present in a string object?

Tags: c#, datetime

in C# , How can i build a DateTime object from a datetime present in a string object ( String strDate="11/11/2009")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) methods.

Simplest case:

```
var result = DateTime.Parse(str);
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) which is also worth knowing about.

There's also [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) and [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) which do the same thing, but won't throw an exception if the date is not valid - will just return a bool.

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using that string format will give you a lot of issues later, such as what is "03/04/2009"?

try using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).